# get 2 days ago query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So for getting last 24 hours query I use something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `mytable` WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

where `timestamp` is a table field with timestamps.

but how can I get the interval between 2 days ago and yesterday.
So

today is 24 ian. I want a query between 22 ian (00:00am) and 23 ian (00:00am)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use `Interval`

```
WHERE `timestamp`
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: It is obvious that the answer is not correct. But for some reason the question owner decided to change its mind after 10 years and mark this answer as an accepted. :)

Answer (score 34):

```
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 
        DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
         AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also try [`DATE_ADD`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) with a minus interval ;)

```
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 
        DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
         AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a query between 22 Jan (00:00 AM) and 22 Jan (11:59 PM)

```
where DATE(timestamp) = DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL  2 day);
```

Example: 
timestamp = 2020-02-24 12:07:19 and Date(timestamp) is 2020-02-24 and `now()` output is current date with time when we use `DATE(now())` then output is Date only,

```
DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL  2 day)
```

is will be 2 days ago.

Comment: This predicate is not sargabe so it will produce index/table scan instead of seek. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Answer (score 1):

Try `BETWEEN`::

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS cnt 

FROM `mytable` 

WHERE timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```