# How to show the rows of this specific mySQL table with a single query and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table in mySQL.
My question is how can I show the last 2 days (yesterday and 2 days ago) unique_visitors, pageviews etc with a single query?

I want this to be dynamically, meaning to no use dates such as `where date ='2016-05-02'`

**The output will be through PHP.**

```
id date       unique_visitors pageviews
 4 2016-05-02            3108     27166
 3 2016-05-01            2189     16848
 2 2016-04-30            2475     20568
 1 2016-04-29            2733     22877
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate:
[get 2 days ago query in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497662/get-2-days-ago-query-in-mysql)

```
WHERE date BETWEEN 
    DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below dynamic query to get last 3 days salary

```
SEKECT *FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATE_COLUMN >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY);
```